# Unable to connect to SFTP-server image deployed in Cloud Run from filezilla client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sftp, google-cloud-run

I added a dockerhub image to the the Container Registry. Then, succesfully ran the image in Cloud Run. The image is https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp. The thing is I'm unable to access the sftp server from FileZilla client.

Any thoughts on what could be going on? Any alternatives? I've considered running the image in a Compute Engine container so that I can actually generate a private key to use it to connect from the FileZilla client. Would appreciate to hear from your wisdom.

Comment: Please move your question to [su], [sf] or [devops.se] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an SFTP server in Cloud Run, but you cannot connect to the server.

The reason is that Cloud Run only supports HTTP Requests and responses. SFTP uses a different protocol (SSH) that is not supported by Cloud Run.